# how to validate checkbox and radio button in yii1

Tags: php, yii

I have following code in my view file:

```
  <div class="form-group snetwork">
        <h3>Post to Social Network Wall</h3>
        <label>Choose Social Networks:</label>
        <div class="row">
            <ul class="social_items">
                <li><span class="label label-info"><?php echo $form->checkbox($model, 'fb')?>  Facebook</span></li>
                <li><span class="label label-warning"><?php echo $form->checkbox($model, 'twitter')?>  Twitter</span></li>
                <li><span class="label label-success"><?php echo $form->checkbox($model, 'telegram')?>  Telegram</span></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <label>Choose Language:</label>
        <div class="row">
            <?= $form->radioButtonList($model, 'language', $model->getLan('language'), array(
                'template' => '<div class="radio " style="float: left; padding-right: 10px; padding-left: 30px">{input}{label}</div>',
                'separator' => '', 'uncheckValue'=>null,
            )); ?>
            <?php echo $form->error($model,'language'); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Case is as follow: when i create a new post and tick social network checkbox and language radio button, it should post news to facebook wall with the specified language. If i leave language radio button unticked, It should show validation error. Therefore, I have created following validation rule in my News model:

```
 public function rules()
        {
            ...
            return array(
            array('language', 'ext.YiiConditionalValidator.YiiConditionalValidator',
                    'if' => array(array('fb, twitter, telegram', 'compare', 'compareValue' => 1)),
                    'then' => array(
                        array('language', 'required'),
                    ),),
```

However, it is not working. Why?

Comment: what is  error , please post error .

Comment: Validation is not working at all.

Comment: It does not show any error.

Answer (score 0):

Please add below lines after each checkbox for display error message.

```
<?php echo $form->error($model,'fb'); ?>
<?php echo $form->error($model,'twitter'); ?>
<?php echo $form->error($model,'telegram'); ?>
```